# Rewrite rules not working for Drupal 7 in subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

So I have a site that is run at example.com and serves as a gateway for the Drupal site that runs in folder `/drupal`. What I want to do, I want to set a cookie on that gateway page on login and then allow access to example.com/drupal and if the cookie is not set, redirect back to example.com.

But my problem is, the rule does not work in the `/drupal` folder in drupal .htaccess, but I tested it and it works fine in the root directory.

The rule is as follows

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !CookieName=test [NC]
   RewriteRule .* http://example.com [L]
```

But for some reason, the rule does not work here and the user can access the /drupal folder without the cookie, but if I place the same rule in / root, then the redirect happens since no cookie with that name is set.

Comment: How do you set your cookie ? Also, is it from a root folder htaccess or a root folder (php?) script ?

Comment: Move this rule as your topmost rule in `drupal/.htaccess`

Answer (score 2):

Quick test on my side to make sure it works, here is an example

`/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

# if no "logged_in" cookie set to "yes", then create it
# cookie is valid for any hosts of .example.com, during 1 minute, for the entire website, not necessarily ssl only, not accessible from javascript
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !logged_in=yes [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=logged_in:yes:.example.com:1:/:false:true]
```

See [this link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co) for the `CO` flag documentation (how to create a cookie through `mod_rewrite`)

`/drupal/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !logged_in=yes [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [R,L]
```

## Scenario

1. Go to `/drupal/` and you should get a redirect to root index
2. Go back to `/drupal/` and it should be OK (since root index has created the cookie)
3. Refresh the current page (`/drupal/`) as many as you want **during 1 minute**, then you'll get a redirect to root index again (cookie has expired)

**Two reasons come to my mind on why you can't make it work**

1. You didn't set your cookie properly
2. Your `/drupal/.htaccess` rule is not executed because placed after main-default rule (put it in the top to make sure)